# Unable to download golang repository by using ansible

Tags: go, ansible

I am trying to download a golang package from github. This is how my playbook looks like

```
- name: Fetch latest gogs repository
      shell: "go get -u github.com/gogits/gogs"
      become: true
      become_user: git
```

It is throwing me following error:

```
{
    "changed": true, 
    "cmd": "go get -u github.com/gogits/gogs", 
    "delta": "0:00:00.002695", 
    "end": "2017-08-22 10:50:02.984669", 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "go get -u github.com/gogits/gogs", 
            "_uses_shell": true, 
            "chdir": null, 
            "creates": null, 
            "executable": null, 
            "removes": null, 
            "warn": true
        }
    }, 
    "rc": 127, 
    "start": "2017-08-22 10:50:02.981974", 
    "stderr": "/bin/sh: go: command not found", 
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/bin/sh: go: command not found"
    ], 
    "stdout": "", 
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

When  I am trying this

```
- name: Fetch latest gogs repository
      shell: "go get -u {{ gogs_repo }}"
      environment:
        - PATH: $PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/bin
        - GOPATH: "{{gogs_home}}/{{ gogs_project_directory }}/src"
        - GOBIN:  "{{gogs_home}}/{{ gogs_project_directory }}/bin"
      become: true
      become_user: git
```

I got this error

```
fatal: [atul-ec2]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to ec2-13-126-203-235.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_gntmXa/ansible_module_command.py\", line 220, in <module>\r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_gntmXa/ansible_module_command.py\", line 163, in main\r\n    os.chdir(chdir)\r\nOSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ec2-user/goprojects/src/src/github.com/gogits/gogs'\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
    "rc": 1
}
```

Here my variables are

```
---
  go_version: go1.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz
  go_url: https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/{{ go_version }}
  go_hash: sha256:702ad90f705365227e902b42d91dd1a40e48ca7f67a2f4b2fd052aaa4295cd95
  go_project_dir: goprojects
  go_home: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}"
  gogs_home: "/home/git"
  gogs_project_directory: "git.varadev.com"
  gogs_repo: github.com/gogits/gogs
```

But when i am using following command on my server

```
which go
```

I got this

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

and when I try manually `go get -u github.com/gogits/gogs`, it is working fine.

Comment: It sounds like the program invoking Go doesn't have the proper `$PATH` configured, or perhaps it ignores the `$PATH` variable.

Comment: @Flimzy then how my ```which go``` and ```go get ``` command working

Comment: Because you're not executing `which go` from within the same program, you're executing it from your shell, and your shell has the proper PATH.

Comment: Why not use the whole path to go in the ansible playbook? Too obvious? Also: Totally unrelated to Go.

Comment: I have already tried the same and it is asking me for gopath and gobin as well which i have already setup in my bashrc.and why i need to do that because i have already exported the same in /etc/profile.d/path.sh as per your documentation

Comment: @Flimzy setup all the environment values and but found a new error.Modified the question according to that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this can help you as a start point:

```
---
- hosts: all
  connection: local 

  tasks:
  - name: check go version
    command: go version
    register: result
    changed_when: no
    ignore_errors: true

  - set_fact:
      go_path: "{{ lookup('env', 'GOPATH') | default(ansible_env.HOME+'/go', true) }}"
    when: not result|failed

  - name: go get gogs
    shell: go get -u github.com/gogits/gogs
    environment:
      GOPATH: "{{ go_path }}"
    register: gogs
    when: not result|failed

  - debug: var=gogs
```

Try to run this on your remote server by typing:

```
ansible-playbook gogs.yml -i localhost,
```

If that works then just later try remotely.

Normally you don't want to do this since you want to execute this remotely over ssh, but since you had tried so far and are getting some errors, probably by trying locally `connection: local` could help to debug more in details this issue.

Comment: Thanks.But by setting up all the environment values i am able to downlad

Comment: did you run it on the server? what is the output?

Comment: Every thing ran fine when i set environment values explicitly

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is too old, but maybe this may help someone.

Ths issue `/bin/sh: go: command not found` it is because you are missing some configuration when Ansible runs, and probably you need to source the bash profile like this:

```
- name: Install gogs
  shell: "source ~/.bash_profile && github.com/gogits/gogs"
  args:
    chdir: /home/{{ owner }}
  become_user: '{{ owner }}'
```

That worked for me.